# TCP WCF Client as windows service connects only under administrator user privilege

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, tcpclient, nettcpbinding

I have been writing windows services for over a decade but this is my first with WCF TCP.

**Problem:**
In a client-server WCF TCP scenario (separate computers), server part works perfect. The client code also works perfect as console app, but when running the same code inside a windows service, it works only under Administrator user. Using Network Service or Local Service (as required for such usages) ends with the following error:

```
The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error 
processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote
host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was
'00:00:59.8938785'.
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host System
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size,
   SocketFlags socketFlags)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32  
   offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)  
System
at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ProcessWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 
   offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, 
   Int32 count)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 
   offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)
```

To simplify the situation, I wrote a WCF server as windows service which utilizes a simple [OperationContract] method which gets a string and echoes it back, so code is not a big deal. Also, this has nothing with timeout settings on server or client, but client user accounts.

Client part (console app and win service, under different users) tested on Windows 10 Pro and Windows Server 2003 with the same results. Server part resides on a Windows Server 2003. All in .Net 4.

**Question:**
A windows service under Administrator user is not an option, so how can I force WCF TCP client on windows service working under Local Service / Network Service?

**Update**
[WCF tracing report](http://www.evrinsoft.com/___files/WCFTrace.rar) in rar format

**Update 2**
[Sample Project](http://www.evrinsoft.com/___files/TestWcfTcp.rar)

Regards

Comment: Add wcf tracing both on client and server. The trace logs will probably help.

Comment: @KD2ND Trace attached, or should I just paste the texts? So far I still believe this is something related to permissions and security, but where and how?

Comment: you attached only the client trace. Add trace to the service (running on your Windows server 2003). It may be related to firewall restrictions, your service listens on specific port and you need to add an in bound rule on the firewall in server.

Comment: @KD2ND Server works fine, there is no firewall on server or client. Client console apps connect and get response, but windows services with the same code, throw same exception CLIENT-SIDE (no trace on server). When I change service Log on account to Administrator in any client PC through Services snap-in, it works like a charm.

Comment: You get 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host' , it does not tell much, add trace to the server and you will probably get more info.